# DNS resolving of localhost subdomains stopped working after resolvconf update

Tags: networking, browser, localhost, web-development, resolvconf

For years I'm using Ubuntu (currently on 18.10) to develop PHP applications on domains like `foo.bar.localhost` for local testing. These domains were resolved to 127.0.0.1 and handled by Apache 2.4. This always worked. The line `127.0.0.1 localhost` is in my `/etc/hosts` like it always was.

Today morning I turned my device on and this did not work anymore. `ping localhost` is still working, but `ping foo.bar.localhost` is not (it still was working yesterday). Surprisingly Chromium is still resolving `foo.bar.localhost`, I assume it's not using the OS for DNS resolving. But I'm mainly using Firefox, which also stopped resolving localhost subdomains.

I didn't change any system-related settings yesterday, but I remember some package updates from yesterday, so I assume there were some changes to some network-related things. Is there any way to get `dpgk` to list install/update dates so that I can find out the exact packages that were updated?

What settings could I check to make resolving subdomains work again system-wide? Are there any known bugs?

Additional information: In `/var/log/dpkg.log` I found a recent entry `upgrade resolvconf:all 1.79ubuntu10 1.79ubuntu10.18.10.1` which sounds relevant. This and the following subsequent lines are the only lines containing the term "resolv" (found with `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep resolv`). So, in the last hours this DNS-relevant package was updated.

Another information: the manual `man systemd-resolved` has the following line:

> The hostnames "localhost" and "localhost.localdomain" (as well as any
>   hostname ending in ".localhost" or ".localhost.localdomain") are
>   resolved to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1.

So this well-defined behaviour stopped working. I also can *not* remember changing anything related to this lowlevel DNS stuff myself.

The exact message when doing `ping foo.bar.localhost` is

```
ping: foo.bar.localhost: Name or service not known
```

Apparently the only bug "fixed" in the new version of resolvconf was this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1817903
which is related to local resolving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was having `resolveconf` installed at all alongside `systemd-resolved`. I removed it by `apt-get purge resolvconf` with root rights. Then everything worked again.

I assume having both installed was a left-over from some previous major version update between Ubuntu releases, which now triggered this strange behaviour.